# Why does PHPDoc error in PHPStorm over this code?

Tags: php, phpdoc

In the following code the @return is underlined red.  I have it expecting an interface to be returned because that is what all of the different Vendor adapters implement.

```
 /**
 * VendorFactory constructor.
 * @param Model $model
 * @return \Traders\Interfaces\VendorAdapterInterface
 */
public function __construct(Model $model)
{
    return $this->createAdapter($model);
}
```

This is the code for the createAdapter which does not have the @return underlined in red.

```
/**
 * @param Model $model
 * @return \Traders\Interfaces\VendorAdapterInterface
 */
public function createAdapter(Model $model)
{
    $type = str_replace('App\Models\\', '', get_class($model)).'s';
    $fqcn = '\Traders\Adapters\\'.$type.'\\'.ucfirst(strtolower($model->name));
    return new $fqcn($model);
}
```

I have tried doing the /** docblock and letting PHPStorm enter what it believes is the return value and it just keeps giving me

```
@return mixed
```

Comment: Because `$fqcn` is a variable, in this case. You're not actually giving it a concrete class. Ignore storm and leave it as is or create a factory.

Comment: Wait what.. `return` in a constructor ?

Comment: thanks Pete that wasn't supposed to be the constructor rather an initialize method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `return` in the constructor.
Constructors do not take return values, they get executed when an instance of that class is instantiated.

Comment: thanks my bad wasn't supposed to be in the constructor should have been the initialize method :)

Comment: Glad to help! To be fair, i think that technically you can actually set return values on __construct functions (because they are just as normal functions) and use them like $ret = $obj->__construct(). Anyway, that's considered a bad practice and is unadvised.